# Community edit rejection, what does second editor see

Tags: discussion, edits

I got a [community edit reject](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7740386), and I was wondering why the edit that rejected mine didn't include some (or all) of the changes I made.

What does a high rep user see when he tries to edit a post with a <strike>pending</strike> suggested edit?

- Does he get options like "reject and edit", "approve and edit" or anything similar?
- Does he actually reject my changes or is rejection a standard automated process?
- If it is automated, why is the rejection counted (`user 5061 had 110 edit suggestions approved, and 10 edit suggestions rejected`)?

Comment: *This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit.* This was rejected because another edit was submitted **outside** the review queue.

Comment: You can tell the difference between a deliberate Reject and Edit and a simple edit conflict because the former will have at least two entries in the review entry history, including one for the reviewer that made the edit. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7733973

Comment: @MartijnPieters I already knew that this is caused by "_another edit outside the review queue_". The duplicate you suggested it quite irrelevant. My post is about "**what options the high rep editor gets** so that i can understand if he **actually** rejects my changes or that the rejection is a standard automated process". I think it's quite clear both in my title, _and_ in the post. But just in case it isnt clear enough, i edit the post.

Comment: @MartijnPieters _What does a high rep user see when he tries to edit a post with a  suggested edit_ - Quite indicative of me knowing the cause of the rejection (but not the details i m after).

Comment: @user5061: the point is that the high-rep user *hasn't seen the suggested edit at all*. That's why there is a collision, they got to editing the post before the suggested edit was submitted, but their edit didn't complete until afterwards.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I know, the information you provide is in the answer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Your decision of locking it is wrong. As I already said **"What are the options a high rep editor gets"** is not answered in the linked duplicate. Also, the duplicate answers why an edit is rejected, not what the high rep editor sees. My post and your suggested dup are irrelevant.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Even by our question titles it is easy to tell that we are asking a very different thing.

Comment: @user5061: There is *nothing different to see* for a high rep user. It also doesn't matter what the user sees, it matters what the user has done.

Comment: @MartijnPieters _"..nothing different to see.."_ - I know..... its in the answer below. However *it is not* in the duplicate you suggested. In other words: the answer to my question doesn't exist in the duplicate, or.. the duplicate is not an actual duplicate.

Comment: @MartijnPieters _".. doesn't matter what the user sees.."_ It does matter to new users that wonder whether their edit was rejected because they did something wrong, or the high rep editor does not see it at all (therefor the initial edit might have been perfectly fine, and the new user didn't do a mistake).

Comment: @user5061: the rejection by community shows that the user *never acted on the suggested edit*. They may or may not have looked at the suggested edit but more often then not they *never saw it in the first place*. You cannot get there with the suggested edit interface. The rejection message means that the post was edited **outside** the review process.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What does a high rep user see when he tries to edit a post with a pending edit?

In that case, the "edit" link is a link to the review, and then he can review it like any other suggested edit: "Approve", "Reject", "Improve Edit" or "Reject and Edit".

But in this case, your edit was not yet pending when the other editor started editing; in that case, he sees nothing. And while your edit was pending, the editor published his edit, leading to an auto-reject (performed by the Community♦ user) because there was an edit conflict.

Comment: What makes a suggested edit "pending"?

Comment: @user5061 A suggested edit is pending when it's still awaiting review from 2k+ users. So until the edit receives 3 Approve or Reject votes, it is "pending".

Comment: One final question. Why is it counted in rejected edits? (check question update)

Comment: @user5061: Because it wasn't and never will be applied. Though don't worry, edit-conflict auto-rejections do not count anywhere else.

Comment: @Deduplicator "_never will be applied_" - This sounds like a bad reason to have it. It might not be counted towards an edit ban, but it is displayed. Why is it displayed? What purpose does it serve?

Comment: @user5061: You could make a [meta-tag:feature-request] to add a conflict count for auto-rejections... Missing that, it's displayed right.